# API Key isn't UUID compliant Error

Tags: 0x

I'm trying to test local 0x-api.
When I do `yarn test` I **dont get any errors**.
When I do `yarn start` or `yarn db:migrate` I **got an error**: `Error: API Key  isn't UUID compliant`. I've only changed the `.env` file.

Traceback:
`/home/roman/0x-api-folder/0x-api/src/config.ts:679 apiKeys.forEach((apiKey) => { ^ Error: API Key  isn't UUID compliant at /home/roman/0x-api-folder/0x-api/src/config.ts:682:27 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) at assertEnvVarType (/home/roman/0x-api-folder/0x-api/src/config.ts:679:21)`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same errors as well after running:

```
Yarn install
Yarn build.
```

Facing the error as this thread mentioned when trying to execute "yarn db:migrate"

Stack trace:

```
yarn run v1.22.17
$ ./node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:run --config ./lib/src/ormconfig.js 
Error during migration run:
Error: API Key  isn't UUID compliant
    at /Users/Documents/0x-api/src/config.ts:751:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at assertEnvVarType (/Users/Documents/0x-api/src/config.ts:748:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Documents/0x-api/src/config.ts:327:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Documents/0x-api/src/ormconfig.ts:3:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Steps that made it work:

1. yarn add @0x/neon-router@0.3.1 separately
2. yarn build
3. docker-compose up (this starts the local ganache, postgres and redis instances)
4. Change env variable ETHEREUM_RPC_URL to: localhost:8545 instead of ganache:8545
5. yarn db:migrate
6. yarn start

Comment: That worked for me! Thank you SOOOO much! Out of curiosity, what is @0x/neon-router doing?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have more of a stack trace available?

Try setting

```
RFQT_API_KEY_WHITELIST_JSON=[]
PLP_API_KEY_WHITELIST_JSON=[]
```

Comment: I have set the variables that you recommended. I get the same error. @JacobEvans