# 0x-API OrderbookService tests fail

Tags: 0x

I managed to start the 0x-api locally (thanks to [this](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api) and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/109359/api-key-isnt-uuid-compliant-error)), however, I am having trouble to run `yarn test`. I am particularly interested in the OrderbookService tests (e.g., how to post an order).

It currently fails with the current error. Would someone know where the issue is?

```
 OrderbookService
    1) "before all" hook in "OrderbookService"


  23 passing (1m)
  1 failing

  1) OrderbookService
       "before all" hook in "OrderbookService":
     Error: Timed out waiting for dependency logs
      at Timeout._onTimeout (test/utils/deployment.ts:135:20)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that the case failed when running docker-compose in a child process. See https://github.com/0xProject/0x-api/blob/8ac6fdb6a0bb44e8ea4365c4dba689ec5d264275/test/utils/deployment.ts#L54

Make sure you have installed docker/docker-compose correctly, and also make sure you are **not** running `docker-compose up` manually, which might cause conflicts.